# Sharing windows authentication accross sites in IIS7/IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a parent website (developed like 5 yrs before) say (sky) which I host in IIS7/IIS7.5 and configure it to use Form authentication and anonymous authentication. The web.config with entries as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="480" name=".ASPXAUTH" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" defaultUrl="~/Home" cookieless="UseDeviceProfile" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>

<location path="cloud">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Now I have a child website (developed 2 days ago) say (cloud) which I host under sky and configure it to use Windows authentication and anonymous authentication. Its own web.config has the following entries.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
 <authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

When I access sky/, I end up on the login form, which is expected. I enter the username/pass and I can browse the parent website absolutely fine.

Unfortunately, when I access sky/cloud/, a username/password prompt box shows up, I enter the correct creds, but it does not authenticate and I cannot browse the child website. It repeatedly throws the creds box.

I switched the priority of authentication provider to do NTLM first over Negotiate on cloud, still no luck.
Why does the new site need to be under the parent site? Gotta blame branding here :(

Any idea's on getting this working would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the user you're using for Windows Authentication on /cloud have the correct permissions set on the application's folder?

Comment: Yes, the permissions on the application folder are set appropriately for the user. I am not sure if the approach of having 2 applications, /cloud sitting inside /sky, use different authentication techniques to be accessed, is even correct? I have been searching online for such an approach but the best I could get is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx